# What is difference between field tables?

Tags: 7, entities, database

What is the difference between a content_field_myfield and field_data_field_myfield in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First used for field in Drupal 6.x versions.

Second used for fields in Drupal 7.x version.

Comment: Is content_node_field D6 too?

Comment: Yes, it's about D6 too.